# Converting string to date time

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date which comes in a string like so:

```
09/25/2014 09:18:24
```

I need it like this (yyyy-mm-dd):

2014-09-25 09:18:24

The object that this date goes into is a nullable date.

Tried this does not work:

```
DateTime formattedDate;
bool result = DateTime.TryParseExact(modifiedDate, "yyyy-MM-dd",
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
               DateTimeStyles.None,
               out formattedDate);
```

Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting String to DateTime C#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net)

Comment: Are you confusing fornmatting and parsing? If the input-string is `09/25/2014` why do you parse it with `yyyy-MM-dd`?

Comment: You also seem to be confused in terms of what a `DateTime` stores... it doesn't *have* a format... it's just a date and time. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763278

Comment: Alright, all three are good suggestions but I need to store it in SQL which takes this 2014-09-25 09:18:24

Comment: @Codehelp What is the column type that you want to insert this `DateTime`? Isn't that a character type I hope..

Comment: @Codehelp I edit my answer, now you should have the correct format for your DB, try it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your question, to convert it as you prefer, do it like this:

```
string originalDate = "09/25/2014 09:18:24";

DateTime formattedDate;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(originalDate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out formattedDate))
{
    string output = formattedDate.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

And then output will have your desired format.

Answer (score 4):

From [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent. **The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly.**

In your case, they are not. Use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format instead.

```
string s = "2014-09-25 09:18:24";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

It is a little bit unclear but if your string is `09/25/2014 09:18:24`, then you can use `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format instead. Just a tip,  [`"/"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) has a special meaning as *replace me with current culture or supplied culture date separator*. That means, if your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or supplied culture's [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) is not `/`, your parsing operation will fail *even* if your format and string matches exactly.

If you have *already* a `DateTime` and you want to format it, you can use [`DateTime.ToString(string)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
dt.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // 2014-09-25
```

or

```
dt.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // 2014-09-25 09:18:24
```

Remember, a `DateTime` does not have *any* implicit format. It just contains date and time values. String representations of them have formats.

Comment: Does not work. TryParseExact fails. Maybe something to do with the slashes not being in the input string. No?

Comment: @Codehelp Which one doesn't work? What is your `modifiedDate` exactly? You have an already a `DateTime` and you want to format it or your have a string with specific format that you want to parse it? Yes `/ character` has a special meaning as I said in my answer but since you use `InvariantCulture`, this is not a problem.

Comment: Ok, tried Stefano's answer, converted it to DateTime and then tried your ToString. It's still the same that goes in.

Comment: @Codehelp What is _still the same that goes in_ exactly? Please be more specific. I told you in my answer as `It is a little bit unclear but if your string is 09/25/2014 09:18:24, then you can use MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss format instead.` With `.ToString()` method, you have a string representations of your `DateTime` with a specific format. And now, you have a problem with try to insert this string value to your database? What is the column type that you want to keep it? And how do you insert it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime  dateOf = Convert.ToDateTime("09/25/2014 09:18:24");
string myFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd";
string myDate = dateOf.ToString(myFormat);  // output 2014-18-25
```

**[Datetime format](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format)**

Comment: Why are you using `ddd`, `MMM` and `d` formats anyway? They are irrelevant with question.

Comment: Still, there is no guarantee that your `CurrentCulture` parses your `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` formated string since you use `Convert.ToDateTime(string)` method without any `IFormatProvider`.